# Checkbox in my windows 8.1 app won't activate in emulator

Tags: checkbox, windows-phone

I know this is going to sound really stupid but is there anything I'm missing because I have a simple page in my windows 8.1 phone app with a checkbox and a button. I can click on the button just fine in the emulator but I can't get the checkbox to check or uncheck at all. I feel really stupid for not being able to do something this simple. Am I missing something here?

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="lblTermsofAgreement"/>
    <CheckBox Name="chkAcceptTerms" Checked="chkAcceptTerms_Checked" Click="chkAcceptTerms_Click" Unchecked="chkAcceptTerms_Unchecked" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="I accept the terms of agreement" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="True"></CheckBox>
    <TextBlock Name="lblTermsError" FontFamily="Red"  Text="" />
    <Button Name="btnAccept" Click="btnAccept_Click" Content="Accept" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the controls are in row 0 column 0 for the grid so there was a control on top of it preventing it from getting checked.  I would either add rows to the grid and set there rows or put the controls in a stack panel.

```
       <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Name="lblTermsofAgreement"/>
                <CheckBox Name="chkAcceptTerms"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="I accept the terms of agreement" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="True"></CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Name="lblTermsError" FontFamily="Red"  Text="" />
                <Button Name="btnAccept" Content="Accept" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Button>
           </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```